# Alterar dinamicamente a imagem de uma imageView (Android Studio)?

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma imageView com dois botões, avançar e retroceder. Em uma galeria de 5 fotos eu gostaria de ficar trocando de imagem de forma que um botão avance uma imagem e o outro retroceda. Sei como fazer apenas pra pular para uma imagem específica. Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um vetor com as imagens:

```
int[] imagensIds = {
    R.drawable.image1,
    R.drawable.image2,
    R.drawable.image3
};

//E um int para saber qual posição

int i = 0;
```

Sua imagem carrega a primeira com a posição de "i":

```
img.setImageResource(imagensIds[i]);
```

E então ao clicar no botão:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 i++;
                 img.setImageResource(imagensIds[i]);
             }
         });
```

Se fosse pra retroceder você usaria "i--"

Mas aí cabe a você fazer um if para verificar se já está na ultima imagem para ele não chegar por exemplo `i = 3` sendo que não existe o index 3 no vetor de imagens

Comment: Me ajudou muito cara, vlw.